# upload binary file base64 encoded and get filename in php

Tags: php

How to get the file name from base64 encoded binary files that posted to php application.

I could get mime type info as in that code block

```
 $finfo = finfo_open();
 $mime_type = finfo_buffer($finfo, $data, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
 finfo_close($finfo);
 // get file type png. jpg
 $ext = $mime_type ? str_replace('image/', '', $mime_type) : 'png';
```

Is it possible to get original file name like mime type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The file contents doesn't contain the file name. Unless it was specified via HTTP parameters, you can't.